# two dimensional array with undefined second dimension

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, audio, multidimensional-array

I have a problem that I'm not sure how to solve. I have a C++ function that opens a .wav file, reads the samples into an array of doubles that has as many indexes as the number of samples in the .wav file, and return a pointer to that array. This works perfectly.

What I'm wanting to do is read more than one .wav file and store them in a two dimensional array. Although I know *how many* arrays there will be, the size of each array will be different, because all .wav files have a different nubmer of samples. I don't know how to properly store this data for multiple files.

Here is the call to wav2sig, the function that opens the .wav and returns a pointer:

```
double* wav2sig(std::string filepath, int & num_samples)
```

And here is the code that I'm working off, roughly.

```
std::string paths[3] = {"man1.wav",
                          "man2.wav",
                          "man3.wav"};

double **data = new double[3][];   //this would work in java, but not here

int num_samples[3];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     data[i] = wav2sig(paths[i], num_samples[i]);
     for(int j = 50; j < 100; j++)
          std::cout << data[i][j] << " ";
     std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I know that the returned pointer has all correct data. I just don't know how to store several of them correctly. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Oddly enough, I tried this right after i posted, and it seems to have worked.


changed
`double **data = new double[3][];`

to
`double **data = new double*[3];`

I guess I wasn't setting the pointer to an array upon creation?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest the use of `std::vector` for the arrays instead of pointers that point to dynamically allocated memory. They are just as easy to use and they take away the headache of managing memory.

### Change the return value of `wav2sig`

```
std::vector<double> wav2sig(std::string filepath);
```

I am guessing `num_samples` was used to return the number of elements in the returned array. When you use `std::vector<double>` as the return type, the size of the returned value will capture that. Hence, there is no need for the additional output argument.

### Use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` for the 2D array.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> data;
```

### Update the loops accordingly

```
// Separate reading of the data from files from outputting the data

// Read the data
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   data.push_back(wav2sig(paths[i]);
}

// Output the data
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   for(size_t j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++)
      std::cout << data[i][j] << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing this. I was worried about the performance implications of using a vector with that many push_back calls. For example, several of the files I am working with are only 10 seconds long, but have ~180,000 samples. This is 180k calls to push back, which I feel will have serious performance implications. 

Aside from that, your implementation will work great.

Comment: Unless you have millions of elements in the vector, you probably won't notice any performance problems.

Comment: Okay. So if i have a vector of ten vectors with 200,000 elements a piece, that would put me at 2,000,000 elements. I suppose I could see some performance issues. Hopefully that doesn't become the case. I can put both versions in the code and choose.